# View Recordings from Recording Breakpoint in "Record & Analyze" (Enterprise Architect)

Tags: reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I am debugging my java application and added a "Start Recording Marker" {1} and an "End Recording Marker" {2} (in source code right click -> Breakpoint -> Add ... Marker).

I also had to add a normal Breakpoint {3} because if I don't, the application gets stuck somewhere in the start up. (StartingFrame is displayed, so a part of the code got executed, but not all of it.)

When I then press the play button {4} in the "Record & Analyze" Window and select the correct Recording Set, I see in the Debug console that the recording is started and later ended {5}. The debugged application itself starts successfully.

However, in the "Record & Analyze" Window it still says "There are no items to show in this view." {6}

How can I get the recorded method calls to be displayed there?

In the end, I want to generate a Sequence Diagram from those recordings. (like [here](http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/908-capture-runtime-method-calls-execution-analyzer))

Images (for the numbers in the { }):
[image: Screenshot of Code]

[image: Screenshot of Record & Analyze and Debug]

Comment: here is the official documentation on the recording feature: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/visual_execution_analysis/using_the_execution_analyzer.html
I do not really know this feature and I couldn't identify the problem looking through it, but maybe you can find something

Comment: Read the guide, but it does not say how to view that history created by the debugger. Perhaps it should automatically appear in "Record & Analyze" and I just did something wrong in the whole setup, or it is a bug (which I doubt though)

Comment: Yes, I am getting a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the Sparx Support:

> The debugger is failing to resolve UNC paths for source files. So, the only workaround is to build it locally, or set up a symbolic link on the laptop to the UNC path and use that.

My source files are at:
//chca6021.eur.beluni.net/a469627$/Documents/workspace/HelloWorld

Moving the project to a local directory (under C:/) solved the problem.